# Use free space on a Mac (with a SSD)

Tags: macos, partitioning, disk-utility

I have a MacBook Air with a 128GB SSD, I installed Yosemite on a second partition then removed it and now I have that:
[image]
50GB of free space and I can't find how to give it to Macintosh HD (the partition), does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you're using a Core Storage logical volume group. If you didn't set this up intentionally yourself, you probably got it by enabling FileVault 2 full disk encryption. Which means your question comes down to the same thing as this one, and the answer for you is probably the same:

[How do I resize a FileVault 2 encrypted partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/315803/how-do-i-resize-a-filevault-2-encrypted-partition)

Comment: Thank you! Even Apple didn't give me a correct answer and yours worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click and drag the bottom of the Macintosh HD partition downward to increase its size with the extra free space and then click apply to apply the changes without deleting the current partitions.

If that does not work, an alternative option would be to back up the Macintosh HD partition with Time Machine and reset/erase the entire partition table. Then you can reinstall Mac OS X with the disk and use the backup to restore your current settings.

Comment: I'm not allowed to click and drag the partition, it's really weird.